# Difference between destructuring in function vs React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I am experiencing a very frustrating issue with regards to object destructuring in my function parameters. I have the following code in one of my components:

```
import React from "react";
import { range } from "../../utils";
import { checkGuess } from "../../game-helpers";

function Guess({ guess, answer }) {
  const guessEmpty = guess === undefined ? true : false;
  const letters = !guessEmpty && checkGuess(guess.value, answer);

  function renderLetter({ letter = undefined, status = undefined } = {}, num) {
    return (
      <span className={`cell ${status}`} key={num}>
        {letter}
      </span>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      {
        <p className="guess">
          {range(5).map((num) => renderLetter(letters[num], num))}
        </p>
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default Guess;
```

The `letters` constant is an array, which will either be set to `false` or consist of a list of objects depending on whether the `guess` input parameter for the `Guess` function is empty or not.

When I pass `letters[num]` (which can be an object, or undefined) into my `renderLetter` function, my `letter` and `status` input parameters are either converted to undefined or strings depending on the input through object destructuring. This all works great.

However, instead of rendering the `<span>` elements by using the `renderLetter` function, I now want to move this to a new component. The code for this component is:

```
import React from "react";

function Letter({ letter = undefined, status = undefined } = {}) {
  return (
    <>
      <span className={`cell ${status}`}>{letter}</span>
    </>
  );
}

export default Letter;
```

Similarly to the way I called the `renderLetter` function, I am now attempting to render the  components:

```
return (
    <>
      {
        <p className="guess">
          {range(5).map((num) => (
            <Letter letter={letters[num]} num={num} />
          ))}
        </p>
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

However, when logging `letter` and `status` parameters inside the `Letter` component, the `letter` parameter returns an object, and the `status` parameter returns undefined. As such, I'm assuming I'm messing up in destructuring the input correctly.

I fail to see why however, since doing it this exact same way does work when using a function inside the same component, while it does not when transferring the code to a separate component.

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your `Letter` component is defined, it takes two props: `letter` and `status`, both expected to be strings or undefined.

But `<Letter letter={letters[num]} num={num} />` does pass an *object* to the `letter` prop, nothing to the `status` prop, and a number to the non-existing (and therefore ignored) `num`  prop. What you want instead is

```
<Letter letter={letters[num]?.letter} status={letters[num]?.status} key={num} />
```

or simpler

```
<Letter {...letters[num]} key={num} />
```

Your problem is not with the destructuring, but rather with the usage of the component which works different than a function call.

---

Btw, in a function component you don't need to default the parameter to an empty object, and you don't have to default anything to `undefined` (though you probably *do* want to default the `status` to the empty string). It'll suffice to write

```
export default function Letter({ letter, status='' }) {
  return (
    <span className={`cell ${status}`}>{letter}</span>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. When you converted the `renderLetter` function into a full component, you forgot the first parameter of a React component is always [the props object](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#step-2-read-props-inside-the-child-component). Since you're now passing `letters[num]` as a prop instead of an argument, it will arrive in the props object under the `letter` key.

```js
// A component like this:
<Letter letter={letters[num]} num={num} />

// Results in a props object like this:
{
  letter: {
    letter: '',
    status: ''
  },
  num: 0
}
```

Your destructuring needs to account for this in your component:

```js
function Letter({ letter: { letter, status } }) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue with the `num`